# SQL Server 2008 R2 ODBC Error: SQL state HTY00

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, odbc, dsn

My application server (say 192.168.100.1) and database server (say 192.168.100.2) both are on the same domain. I'm trying to create an ODBC connection from the application server to a SQL Server database on the database server, but at the time of login it generates this error:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Login
Connection failed:
SQL State: 'HYT00'
SQL Sever Error: 0
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Login timeout expired
```

[image: DSN Error description]

I've checked all configuration for SQL Server and tried possible solutions without resolving this issue.

**Important:**
A DSN can be successfully created from my own PC but when attempting this server to server as described above, ODBC is facing this problem.

Comment: No Ans from last 16hours? :)

Comment: On a hunch, update everything.  SQL Server, ODBC drivers, etc.  Confirm that your own PC has the same ODBC driver (name, version, DLL) as your app server does, and that your DSNs are defined identically.

Comment: Thank you but problem is not yet solved.

Comment: Don't you think it is might be a network related issue?
Both system can ping each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have got the solution. Sometimes, if SQL Server can't be found on network by its name while creating DSN in windows, the logging in takes time more than usual which tells ODBC manager that Database Server we are looking for is not responding or responding too late. 
Solution.
Instead of selecting server from the list while making dsn, use '*server-ip\SQLExpress*'.
e.g 192.168.100.2\SQLExpress.
Thats All.